# Get output of a python script into a variable in Jenkinsfile

Tags: python, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Python script which returns a string on stdout. The value rerturned by the python script can be collected in a bash script like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

outputString=$(./my_python_script.py -some_parameter 2>&1)
echo "The output string is $outputString"
```

On a *scripted pipeline* with the `Jenkinsfile` written in Groovy, I need to call my python script from the `Jenkinsfile` and collect the output into a variable in the `Jenkinsfile`.

**Question:**
How do I do this provided that my Jenkinsfile run on a macOS node. Following is the way how I can at least get the output in a shell variable.

```
stage('My build') {
    node('my_build_node') {
        sh 'output_string=$(./my_python_script.py -some_parameter 2>&1) && sh 'echo The output_string is $output_string'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def outputString = sh returnStdout:true, script:'./my_python_script.py -some_parameter 2>&1'
println "the output string is: ${outputString}"
```

`sh` step parameters details:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script