# Jenkins if else using sh stdout not working

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm running sh command in Jenkins pipeline that runs a python script.
The last line in my python script is `print('Hello', file=sys.stdout)`
RUN_RESULTS in the Jenkinsfile does return "Hello". "Hello" prints out when running `echo RUN_RESULTS`.

But `if (RUN_RESULTS.toString().trim().equals('Hello'))` or `if (RUN_RESULTS.toString().trim()=='Hello')` is equating to False. Seems I cannot validate a string from the stdout return.

```
script {
  RUN_RESULTS = sh (script: 'python main.py', returnStdout: true)

  if (RUN_RESULTS.toString().trim().equals('Hello')) {
     echo 'It works'
  } else {
     echo 'Always evaluating to false'
  } 
}
```

Comment: CAn you `println RUN_RESULTS` and screenshot your build console

Comment: The only output from the build console is the word Hello

Comment: Im asking for the screenshot because if I modify `sh(script: 'python main.py', returnStdout: true)` to `(script: 'echo Hello', returnStdout: true)` it works fine.  So something else is wrong, and you already think it's printing Hello ( with a capital H ) so reiterating it doesn't give me any real confidence that it's actually doing that

Comment: I solved it with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67168939/get-output-of-a-python-script-into-a-variable-in-jenkinsfile?rq=1.    I took your suggestion and printed, println RUN_RESULTS, but didnt realize at first the entire run was in this variable, the entire output. Thanks